# Understanding comparator usage

Tags: java, comparator

while looking at a simple Comparator usage example:

```
Comparator<Developer> byName = new Comparator<Developer>() {
@Override
public int compare(Developer o1, Developer o2) {
    return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding this method declaration I've never seen such thing before.

In addition, I tried to do something else:
I created a class that have inner classes that implement Comparator:

```
class Test{
class A implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(int a, int b) {
        // Do something
    }
}


class B implements Comparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(int a, int b) {
        return  a > b ? 1 :A.compare(a, b);
    }
}
}
```

A.compare(a,b) doesn't compile. It asks me to to make A and compare static but then I don't override the method compare of the comparator class.

Plus, saying I want to use the method A in another class

```
class C {
private int foo(){
Test.A()
}
}
```

it doesn't work also 
how do I do that properly?
Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about the first code snippet? Maybe that it's an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)?

Comment: `A.compare(a,b)` doesn't compile because you need to call `compare` on an *instance*  of `A`, not on the class itself (it's not a static method). Try: `new A().compare(a, b)`.

Comment: There is no constructor declaration here.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a `Comparator<Something>`, then you are using a *parameterized type* (in this case: `Something`).

The method signiture of `compare` needs to match this type.

So, try:

```
public int compare(Integer a, Integer b)
```

Comment: then shouldn't the signiture be `compare(Integer a, Integer b)` ? Remember in java that `int` and `Integer` are different types, even though they can sometimes be used interchangeably due to *autoboxing*